# flutter bloc cubit best practice with multiple firebase request

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore, flutter-layout, bloc

i'm working on an app with firebase , in one screen i need to get a lot of documents at once
first image of the day , the stats of user , the pending request , friends stats , and then country stats.

*sorry for my naming btw

```
class HomeSmileLoading extends HomeState {
const HomeSmileLoading();
@override
List<Object> get props => [];
}
```

and similar to this i have HomeStatsLoading , friends stats ...

this is how i execute the the code in the start of the app

```
HomeCubit() : super(HomeInitial()) {
imageOfday();
getStats();
//...
}
```

i feel like there is better way to do this .. 
 if anyone have any tips or idea i appreciate your help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, it's not wrong what you are doing, just you won't be able to load all the data in parallel. Also, a single Cubit in your case is responsible to handle all the different data you should load - it's not very flexible.

What I would recommend you to do is:

1. Create a different Cubit for each data source/feature (one for stats, one for requests and so on).
2. Each Cubit would have different states: Initial, Loading, Loaded, Error - these could be different based on your needs.
3. When creating/providing Cubits for your app, call the init/load function on each Cubit to load the initial data:

   ```
   MultiBlocProvider(
     providers: [
       BlocProvider<StatsCubit>(
         create: (BuildContext context) => StatsCubit()..getStats(),
       ),
       BlocProvider<ImageCubit>(
         create: (BuildContext context) => ImageCubit()..imageOfday(),
       ),
       BlocProvider<AnyOtherCubit(
         create: (BuildContext context) => AnyOtherCubit()..loadData(),
       ),
     ],
     child: ChildA(),
   )
   ```

It is a good practice to split Cubits per feature and making them responsible for only a single thing (e.g. handling authentication, user statistics, any specific data, etc.).

Comment: thank you so much man i really appreciate it <3